# VisualEditor breaking MediaWiki server

Tags: server, 19.10, mediawiki

I set up an Ubuntu 19.10 server running a private wiki with MediaWiki. Everything works well until I try to add VisualEditor following [MediaWiki's manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor#Parsoid_Authentication_Without_Forwarding_Cookies): when I edit my LocalSettings.php file adding

```
if ( !isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) OR $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1'    ) {
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = true;
}
```

and reboot the machine the server stops working. If I try to visit the main page I get a blank page without any output. I'm sure the problem is in those lines because if I comment them out the wiki works again, but I can't understand where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Mismatched braces.</strike>

See also [this page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug) on debugging basics in general.

Comment: I can't see where mismatched braces are...

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the code. In any case, you should establish what the error is - see the linked doc on how to display or log PHP errors.